# Draw order of PointPlacemarks

Tags: java, worldwind

Is there a way to fix the drawing order of PointPlacemarks in World Wind?

Even in the [Placemarks example](https://github.com/nasa/World-Wind-Java/blob/master/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/Placemarks.java) the ordering of **Placemark B** and the Audio Placemark can change just by moving the mouse at certain zoom levels:

[image]

[image]

So far I have tried:

- Adding PointPlacemarks to separate layers
- Using `RenderableLayer.setRenderables` rather than `RenderableLayer.addRenderable`
- [Related question on World Wind forums](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?26612-PointPlacemark-AlwaysOnTop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hacky solution** (requires modifying World Wind source code)

In `gov.nasa.worldwind.render.DrawContextImpl` change `orderedRenderables` from

```
protected PriorityQueue<OrderedRenderableEntry> orderedRenderables =
    new PriorityQueue<OrderedRenderableEntry>(100, new Comparator<OrderedRenderableEntry>()
    {
        public int compare(OrderedRenderableEntry orA, OrderedRenderableEntry orB)
        {
            double eA = orA.distanceFromEye;
            double eB = orB.distanceFromEye;

            return eA > eB ? -1 : eA == eB ? (orA.time < orB.time ? -1 : orA.time == orB.time ? 0 : 1) : 1;
        }
    });
```

to

```
protected Queue<OrderedRenderableEntry> orderedRenderables = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

(or modify the comparator to do what you want). This will fix the drawing order.

**Alternate solution** (does not require modifying World Wind source code)

Extend `PointPlacemark` and override `makeOrderedRenderable()`:

```
public class OrderedPointPlacemark extends PointPlacemark {
    public OrderedPointPlacemark(Position position) {
        super(position);
    }
    @Override
    protected void makeOrderedRenderable(DrawContext dc) {
        super.makeOrderedRenderable(dc);

        if (this.intersectsFrustum(dc) || this.isDrawLine(dc)) {
            dc.pollOrderedRenderables();
            dc.addOrderedSurfaceRenderable(this);
        }
    }
}
```